# How to tell a geom_rect the locations of a bar placed by geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar chart and I want to use a geom_rect to put a rect above the bars ...

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-tribble(
  ~Type,~Value,
  "X", 23,
  "Y", 33
)
df
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Type,y=Value))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_point(aes(y=Value*1.3),color="red")
```

The `geom_point` is easy, but for a `geom_rect`, I need to specify
`xmin`/`xmax` and I have no idea how to find these?

Answer (score 0):

Basically a discrete scale is still a numeric scale where the categories are put at integer values, i.e. the first category is put a position `1`, the second at `2`, ... . To place a rect on top of the bars you could therefore convert your categories to integer positions via `as.numeric(factor(Type))`. These positions could then be used to set the `xmin/xmax` needed for `geom_rect`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~Type, ~Value,
  "X", 23,
  "Y", 33
)

rect_width <- .9 # default width of bars in geom_col

ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = Value)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(aes(y = Value * 1.3), color = "red") +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = as.numeric(factor(Type)) - rect_width / 2,
    xmax = as.numeric(factor(Type)) + rect_width / 2,
    ymin = Value * 1.1,
    ymax = Value * 1.5,
  ), fill = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. Many thanks stefan.